# Pointing my domain name to a subdomain on another site

Tags: dns, domain-name

I've got a new domain name (matprichardson.co.uk), and I'd like to set it up so that when users visit it uses hosting and displays the pages at mat.2toria.com.

I've tried forwarding, but this didn't do what I wanted.  It either forwarded directly, or allowed me to display my page in a frame, which again isn't really what I want, I don't think.

My domain name provider (123-reg) has some settings for managing DNS (A, MX, CNAME, TXT, SRV).  Would I be right in thinking that using this would give me the results I want?

I have tried to read through the instructions on the 123-reg website but I've not got very far.  Here's what I've done so far but it isn't working:-

[image: DNS Settings in 123-reg control panel]

Any ideas what I should be entering here for this to work correctly, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Cname will do what you want and anyone who visits `www.matprichardson.co.uk` will resolve to `mat.2toria.com`, however, the server at `mat.2toria.com` need to be set up to accept a hostheader of `www.matprichadson.co.uk` or you will just hit the default page (as it is currently doing).

If you can't contact the server owner to do that, I recommend creating a page that has a full page iframe that forwards on, or, simply host a page on 1and1 that forwards to the other page (I'll be shocked if they don't have a built in forwarder type feature).